# add node to specific child by xpath in Dart

Tags: xml, flutter, dart, xpath

I would like to add node as second child of a parent node (as second book in shelf)

```
        ///dart example/test.dart
    import 'package:xml/xml.dart';
    import 'dart:io';
    
    const bookshelfXml = '''<?xml version="1.0"?>
        <bookshelf>
          <book>
            <title lang="es">Growing a Language</title>
            <price>29.99</price>
          </book>
          <book>
            <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
            <price>39.95</price>
          </book>
          <price>132.00</price>
          <book>
            <title lang="en">The War of the Worlds</title>
            <price>12.5</price>
          </book>
        </bookshelf>''';
    final document = XmlDocument.parse(bookshelfXml);
    void buildBook(XmlBuilder builder, String title, String language, num price) {
      builder.element('book', nest: () {
        builder.element('title', nest: () {
          builder.attribute('lang', language);
          builder.text(title);
        });
        builder.element('price', nest: price);
      });
    }

final builder = XmlBuilder();
void main() async {
  buildBook(builder, 'This is the second book in shelf', 'en', 99.99);
  document.rootElement.children.add(builder.buildFragment());
  const filename = './example/git.xml';
  var wfile = await File(filename).writeAsString(document.toXmlString());
}
```

but the code only add the book to the last child of the shelf, not at the second position.

Please help me how to put it at right position on the shelf (may be cut and insert it in to the second position and move the others downward).

Comment: Isn't there a `children.insert(pos, node)` method in Dart xml? Try that.

Comment: Thanks Martin "children.insert(pos, node)" I did not found that for 1st time.